# Create common variable based on earliest and latest date and a common string in another column in R?

Tags: r, matching

I am newish in R and currently I am working on a clinical dataset in long format that includes a patient ID, followed by a treatment and its start and end date.
Some of the patients include more than one treatment and some of them are wrongly coded, for example some patients are receiving the "f" treatment but because is given monthly instead of receiving "f" treatment from 199x-200x they are receiving every application as a separate treatment; resulting in some patients receiving "f" correctly coded but some has ~50 different "f" treatments (expressed as different rows) with a unique start and end date every month from where I want to choose the earliest and latest to calculate the real time on treatment.

The data looks like this:

```
set.seed(0)

patient_id <- sample(1:10, size = 100, replace = TRUE)
treatment <- sample(letters[1:6], size = 100, replace = TRUE)
start_date <- seq(as.POSIXct('1990/01/01'), as.POSIXct('2020/01/01'), by = "100 days")
start_date <- sample(start_date, size = 100, replace = TRUE)
start_date <- as.Date(start_date)
df <- data.frame(patient_id, treatment, start_date)
df <- df %>%
  mutate(real_end_date = start_date + sample(1:1e4, size = 100, replace = TRUE))
df$end_date <- as.Date(ifelse(df$patient_id <= 5 & df$treatment == "f", 
                          df$start_date %m+% months(1),
                          df$real_end_date))
```

Can you help me how to figure how to code "f" treatment as an unique variable instead of a long table with a lot of repetition in only some of the "f" patients.

EDIT: In plain words what I am trying to accomplish is to tell R that if the ID and the treatment is the same, choose the earliest date in the column "start_date" and the latest date in the column "end_date" regardless if they observations are not in the same row.

Comment: your code doesn't run. Specifically, what is %m+%?

Comment: I am sorry, I miss the package library(lubridate)

Comment: ...........huh?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're wanting to use [`summarise()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise.html):

```
library(dplyr)

df |> summarise(start_date = min(start_date), end_date = max(real_end_date), .by = c(patient_id, treatment))
```

Output:

```
   patient_id treatment start_date   end_date
1           9         c 1998-03-20 2040-03-18
2           4         b 1991-05-16 2035-11-18
3           7         c 2003-06-02 2040-04-21
4           1         c 2001-10-10 2038-02-28
5           2         a 1997-12-10 2019-07-16
6           7         e 2015-03-11 2020-10-03
7           2         f 1990-04-11 1992-04-11
8           3         f 1990-10-28 2028-09-17
9           1         f 2009-06-10 2028-07-16
10          5         d 1999-08-02 2027-06-07
11         10         a 1990-04-11 2012-10-14
12          6         e 1997-09-01 2025-07-19
13         10         e 1996-07-28 2042-04-02
14          7         f 2005-01-22 2036-03-25
15          9         a 1997-05-24 2025-01-10
16          5         c 1997-02-13 2040-05-01
17          5         f 2018-10-01 2031-10-02
18          9         f 2009-09-18 2016-07-05
19          2         d 1993-11-01 2031-12-10
20          1         d 2006-09-14 2006-11-09
21          6         a 1997-05-24 2025-09-19
22         10         b 2001-03-24 2039-01-13
23         10         c 2007-07-11 2037-04-04
24          6         d 2003-06-02 2040-01-22
25          4         a 1999-11-10 2030-09-01
26          4         c 2009-03-02 2018-11-22
27          7         d 1990-10-28 2040-07-30
28          6         b 1998-10-06 2026-07-08
29          8         d 2017-12-05 2044-05-01
30          8         b 1995-03-16 2015-03-02
31          7         b 2006-02-26 2022-11-08
32          3         b 2018-03-15 2018-07-14
33          2         c 1993-01-05 2019-10-08
34          6         c 2015-03-11 2018-03-30
35          6         f 2011-08-19 2028-11-25
36          3         e 2009-12-27 2026-04-25
37          3         c 2016-07-23 2043-11-14
38          8         a 1993-11-01 2014-09-17
39          1         e 1996-04-19 2019-05-21
40          8         e 2001-07-02 2044-01-16
41          9         e 1993-07-24 2011-03-31
42          4         f 2012-03-06 2036-12-15
43          1         a 1990-07-20 2023-09-18
44          7         a 2009-03-02 2016-12-03
45          3         a 2019-01-09 2034-08-12
46          2         e 2009-09-18 2036-03-30
47          8         f 2014-12-01 2038-10-02
48          5         b 2011-01-31 2027-07-23
```